# Cannot install pip packages after installing jython

Tags: python, pip, jython, archlinux

> Failed to execute process '/opt/jython/bin/pip'. Reason:
>   The file '/opt/jython/bin/pip' specified the interpreter '/build/jython/pkg/jython/opt/jython/bin/jython', which is not an executable command.

Here is the error occurring whenever I issue a pip command. I `merged BlackArch repositories in my Arch Linux build.` This installed `jython` on which `sjet` depends. So I don't wanna remove it either. What should I do?

*Edit:* I removed sjet and jython to see if pip worked. It did. A reinstall of Jython recreated the issue again.

Comment: Hi, I know it's fairly basic, but could you share the state of the PATH environment variables in your profiles before and after install? It is possible jython has been placed in the PATH being used by sjet and other things before CPython.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there's no change in the PATH variable. Actually, I'll close this issue. I figured out that I can continue life without sjet and Python xD